# Properties are null while DataBind

Tags: web-part, spgridview

I'm having a spgridview in a visual webpart. The datasource of this gridview is written in the ascx-file and has a selectmethod in codebehind.

The problem is that while the datasource does it'S databinding all properties in the webpart are emtpy or zero but were filled before. Additionally to this when i set a property while databinding the property is emtpy or zero after databinding.

How can I access the properties while databindig?

Comment: Are you talking about web part properties? It would be helpful if you provided some of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that you have to use the Selectparameters when using a Databind. All other properties are not working while in Databind.